# Delete multiple rows according to a pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm working with an Excel sheet of 256,923 cells data and I need to delete 29 cells after each single cell.
If I would do it manually, it would take me hours. So, is there anything I can do to reduce efforts and time? or a code I can write?

Comment: A sample data would make it easier to answer

Comment: The cells that you want to delete are in the same column?

Comment: @Sam,
the cells are in rows and different columns.

Comment: @pun,
I will try to post a sample.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a helper column, just enter a new column with a formula:

`=MOD(ROW(),30)`

This will assign number

- 1 to rows 1, 31, 61, 91 ...
- 2 to rows 2, 32, 62, 92 ...
- ...
- 0 to rows 30, 60, 90 ...

So if you wan't to keep e.g. rows 2, 32, 62... then just filter out `2` in your new column and delete what's visible.